# index-match pulling the wrong information in my multiple criteria search

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Having an issue with my index match pulling the wrong information in my multiple criteria search.  The link below will take you to the file.

Breakdown:

- on the 'DG50' tab, E10 is supposed to tell me the number of shares I have based on the date above.
- The number of shares is being calculated on the 'DG50 Data'tab
- The number being sent back is the share price, not the shares

I need E10 to produce the 3.08 number highlighted on the data tab.  Any thoughts?

Thanks

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cJ9ilqnEnpf3ruYcrrjWw9E3sU1e-PK3x0ZAEX1MfYw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Match to pull the Row number goes through your entire column B but the range you use for the index starts at row 3. This means that you will have an offset of 2 rows. You should correct you formula hence to look like:

```
=INDEX('DG50 Data'!$A$3:$AB$200,MATCH(DG50!B10,'DG50 Data'!B:B,0)-2,MATCH(DG50!$E$8,'DG50 Data'!$2:$2,0))
```

This is why its returning the value 2 rows down. Regards,